# Angular CanActivate guard - createUrlTree relative navigation

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I currently have a route guard such as

```
export class EntityGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private readonly router: Router, ...) {}

  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> {

  ...
```

This guard is activated for the URL

```
basePath/select/10/123
```

which means

```
basePath/select/:type/:id
```

---

When a certain condition is met, I need to force navigation back to

```
basePath/select/:type
```

How can I do that using `createUrlTree`? E.g.

```
if (...) {
   return of(this.router.createUrlTree([../', type]));
}
```

I'd need to set the

```
{ relativeTo: parent }
```

option. However I can't seem to find a way to do it.

---

My current solution is

```
private navigateBack(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
  const end = state.url.indexOf(route.url[route.url.length - 1].path);
  const parentUrl = state.url.slice(0, end);
  return of(this.router.createUrlTree([parentUrl]));
}
```

Which I really don't like. String manipulation is big no for me.

Comment: Note that `createUrlTree([parentUrl])` won't work if the `parentUrl` has matrix parameters. Return `parseUrl(parentUrl)` instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm felt at the same situation, and got similar solution. The main issue is if we inject `ActivateRoute` using the constructor, we get the previous route.
They are planing to pass `ActivateRoute` at the `canActivate` method instead of the `ActivatedRouteSnapshot`.

This is the ticket: 
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/22763

you can keep your solution until the angular team create better solution.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks! On Angular 7.2.14, constructor-injecting `ActivatedRoute` produces `null`. So I think it is really unusable. I was hoping for Angular 8, but it seems it won't be done

Answer (score 2):

I have a workaround to get the URL Segment for current route:

```js
  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot,
  ): boolean | UrlTree | Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> {
    const currentUrlFragments = route.pathFromRoot.flatMap((s) => s?.url ?? []).map((s) => s.path);
    return this.router.createUrlTree([...currentUrlFragments, '../']);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is one more workaround getting the url from `Router` like this `this.router.getCurrentNavigation()?.extractedUrl.toString()`

Full example below:

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MyGuard implements CanActivate, CanLoad {
  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ):
    | Observable<boolean | UrlTree>
    | Promise<boolean | UrlTree>
    | boolean
    | UrlTree {
    return this.redirect();
  }

  canLoad(
    route: Route,
    segments: UrlSegment[]
  ):
    | Observable<boolean | UrlTree>
    | Promise<boolean | UrlTree>
    | boolean
    | UrlTree {
    return this.redirect();
  }

  private redirect() {
    let url = this.router.getCurrentNavigation()?.extractedUrl.toString() || '/';
    return this.router.createUrlTree([url, 'other', 'relative','path']);
  }
}
```

Guarding a path like `hello/:name` with the above guard would result navigating to `hello/:name/other/relative/path`, e.g. `hello/world/other/relative/path`.

Answer (score 2):

Since the 14.1, angular team has added an helper to create relative UrlTree from a ActivatedRouteSnapshot, called `createUrlTreeFromSnapshot`:

- Feature: https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/45877
- Doc: https://angular.io/api/router/createUrlTreeFromSnapshot

```js
canActivate(
        route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        state: RouterStateSnapshot
    ): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
  // Will redirect relatively to the commands
  return of(createUrlTreeFromSnapshot(route, ['../relativeFragment']));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it still doesn't work in angular 12, I wrote myself an util function to never come back here googling ;) It behaves like I would expect router to behave, which means it takes path like './../../relative' and goes relatively deep as needed to create UrlTree.

```
export const createRelativeUrlTree = (
  relativePath: string, // pass your path like this: './../foronelevel' './../../fortwolevels'
  currentUrl: string, // e.g. from RouterStateSnapshot .url
  router: Router,
): UrlTree => {
  if (!relativePath.startsWith('./../')) { throw new Error('createRelativeUrlTree: Path needs to start with \'./../\'!') }

  let levels = 1;
  let path = relativePath.substring(5); // removes obligatory './../' for first level of relativeness

  while (path.startsWith('../')) {
    ++levels;
    path = path.substring(3);
  }
  
  let reversedUrl = currentUrl.split('').reverse();
  let wantedLevelSlashIdx = 0;

  for (let i = levels; i > 0; i--) {
    wantedLevelSlashIdx = reversedUrl.findIndex(sign => sign === '/');
    reversedUrl = reversedUrl.slice(wantedLevelSlashIdx + 1);
  }

  const baseUrl = reversedUrl.reverse().join('');
  const compactUrlParts = [baseUrl, path].filter(part => !!part); // removes empty url parts
  return router.createUrlTree(compactUrlParts);
};
```

Comment: I'm back to Angular 17 (from 8). I suspect it still doesn't have this built-in functionality, right?